# Proving that the graph of a function is closed

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $F$ be a metric spaces and $(x_n)$ a sequence in $F$ without limit points. Define $f:\{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}\cup \{0\}\to F$ by letting $f(0)=t$ with $t\in F$ and $f(1/n)=x_n$.

How to prove that the graph of $f$ is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\{(1/n, x_n)\}$ had limit points, then so would $\{x_n\}$, hence it has no limit points. Then $\operatorname{Cl}(\{(1/n,x_n)\})=\{(1/n, x_n)\}$. Note that $\operatorname{Gr}(f)=\{(1/n, x_n)\}\cup\{(0, t)\}$. Since 
$$
\operatorname{Cl}(A\cup B)=\operatorname{Cl}(A)\cup\operatorname{Cl}(B)
$$
then
$$
\operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Gr}(f))
=\operatorname{Cl}(\{(1/n,x_n)\}\cup \{(0,t)\})
=\operatorname{Cl}(\{(1/n,x_n)\})\cup \operatorname{Cl}(\{(0,t)\})
$$
$$
=\{(1/n,x_n)\}\cup \{(0,t)\}
=\operatorname{Gr}(f)
$$
So $\operatorname{Gr}(f)$ is closed.

Comment: Note that the OP is asking for a proof that the graph of $f$ is closed, not the image of $f$.

Comment: @AlexBecker note that OP accepted the answer so I do not understand the downvotes.

Comment: Maybe this is a beautiful example of a homework question asked without any prior research : OP didn't bother to check for the definition of *graph* before asking...

Comment: well in that case I'll write another solution

Comment: @Norbert I realize the OP accepted the solution, and I think this was done in confusion. This question is actually in response to an answer I gave to a previous question of the OP, where I left proving the graph was closed to the OP.

Comment: @Alex Becker, if $E$ and $F$ are closed metric then $E\times F$ is closed. Note that $${\rm{graph }}\,\, f=((1/ n, x_n)\cup(0, t))=((1/n)\cup \{0\})\times((x_n)\cup \{t\})$$ Norbert tested that $(x_n)\cup\{t\}$ is closed, as $(1/n)\cup \{0\}$ is also closed then ${\rm{graph }}\,\, f$ is closed

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero, this is wrong, because $(1/n,t)\in E\times F$

Comment: you're right Norbert!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Note : I define the graph of $f:X \to Y$ to be $\{(x,f(x)) \mid x \in X\}$

Let $y_p \in F \times \mathbb{R}$ be a convergent sequence of the graph $G$ of $f$. If it contains $(0,t)$ infinitely often, then its limit is $(0,t)$ which is in $G$.

In the opposite case, we have a sequence $a_p$ such that $y_p= (\frac 1 {a_p}, x_{a_p})$ beyond a certain rank, and  by restriction, we can assume that this is valid from $p=0$.

Suppose $(a_p)_p$ is unbounded, then we can extract $(a_{\phi (p)})_p$ which goes to $+\infty$. So $(x_{a_{\phi (p)}})_p$ is divergent because $(x_p)_p$ has no limit points. So $(y_{\phi (p)})_p$ is divergent (projection is continuous). So our sequence $(y_p)_p$ has a divergent subsequence and thus is divergent. That is absurd so $(a_p)_p$ is bounded.

So $(y_p)_p$ lives in a discrete space, and since it is convergent it is stationary, which guarantees convergence toward an element of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{(a_n,f(a_n))\}_n$ be a convergent sequence of elements of the graph $G$ of $f:E=\{0\}\cup\mathbb{N}\to F$, and $(a,b) \in E\times F$ its limit. Since $\{f(a_n)\}_n$ is convergent and $\{x_n\}_n$ has no limit point, therefore the sequence $\{f(a_n)\}_n$ must be finite, i.e. there exists some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(a_n)=f(a_k)$ for every $n \ge k$. Thus $b=f(a_k)$, and $(a,b) \in G$.